# jquery datepicker set minDate based-on data-attribute ($(this).attr())

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

***Page Body***

```
<div>Project Name</div>
<div>Project Scopes Details</div>
<div id="scopeFrame">
    <div id="scope01">
        <div>Scope1 Name</div>
        <div>Start Date: 1 June 2015</div>
        <div>Completed Date: <input id="completed_date_1" class="completed_date" type="text" data-mindate="1-6-2015" /></div>
    </div>

    <div id="scope02">
        <div>Scope1 Name</div>
        <div>Start Date: 15 June 2015</div>
        <div>Completed Date: <input id="completed_date_2" class="completed_date" type="text" data-mindate="15-6-2015" /></div>
    </div>

    <div id="scope03">
        <div>Scope1 Name</div>
        <div>Start Date: 22 June 2015</div>
        <div>Completed Date: <input id="completed_date_3" class="completed_date" type="text" data-mindate="22-6-2015" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// SET jQuery UI calender for completion date
    $('.completed_date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd MM yy",
        minDate: new Date($(this).attr('data-minDate')), // min date is scope start date
        maxDate: new Date(), // max date is ToDay, current date;
    });
});
```

Some how i am unable to get the min-date for date-picker.
Mindate is the scope start date which i have set as **data-mindate** in the complete date text box.
any suggestions ?

Comment: `'data-minDate'` there is typo error.it's actually `'data-mindate'`

Comment: 1. should be 'data-mindate' not data-minDate'
2. use id for each date input type.

Comment: after correcting  attr('data-minDate')  to attr('data-mindate') also did not worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.each($('.completed_date'), function() {
    var mindate = $(this).attr('data-minDate');
   $(this).datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd MM yy",
        minDate: new Date(mindate),
        maxDate: new Date(), // max date is ToDay, current date;
    });
});

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>Project Name</div>
<div>Project Scopes Details</div>
<div id="scopeFrame">
    <div id="scope01">
        <div>Scope1 Name</div>
        <div>Start Date: 1 June 2015</div>
        <div>Completed Date: <input id="completed_date_1" class="completed_date" type="text" data-mindate="02 February 2016" /></div>
    </div>

    <div id="scope02">
        <div>Scope1 Name</div>
        <div>Start Date: 15 June 2015</div>
        <div>Completed Date: <input id="completed_date_2" class="completed_date" type="text" data-mindate="12 February 2016" /></div>
    </div>

    <div id="scope03">
        <div>Scope1 Name</div>
        <div>Start Date: 22 June 2015</div>
        <div>Completed Date: <input id="completed_date_3" class="completed_date" type="text" data-mindate="14 February 2016" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try minDate: new Date($(this).attr('data-mindate', 'your date'))

Comment: what 'your date' suppose to be,